# Finding XML element, and reading attribute in Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, xml-parsing

I'm pretty new to XML, and very new to XML in Matlab, but am trying to read attributes from a (very large) XML file.

The file looks like this:

```
<WorkGen>
 <experiment>
  <parameters>
  <exptid> abcd </exptid>
  <years> 400 </years>
  </parameters>
 </experiment>
 <experiment>
  <parameters>
  <exptid> wxyz </exptid>
  <years> 90 </years>
  </parameters>
 </experiment>
 ...
</WorkGen>
```

Given an experiment ID (exptid), I'd like to be able to find the value of years, using Matlab.  Anyone know of a straightforward way of doing this?

---

Note I tried [XML2Struct](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct), but got an out of memory error when trying to read in the XML:

Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Error using org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl/parse
Failed to retrieve Exception Message
Error in xmlread (line 98)
parseResult = p.parse(fileName);
Error in xml2struct (line 53)
        xDoc = xmlread(file);

Exception in thread "TimerQueue" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: What's "very large"? How many kb or mb? How many lines?

Comment: maybe about 100,000 large, so not huge, but big enough that I get memory problems using XML2Struct

Comment: And please edit your question to provide the full error message – line numbers and all.

Comment: will do, though I don't think it's necessary to do this via XML2Struct, and other solutions might not run into the same issues (while being more applicable to those that don't want to download an extra function from the Mathworks File Exchange).

Comment: All solutions that I'm aware of (including `XML2struct`) will be based on a Java parser. It would be be nice to know if the error is from the parser or elsewhere in the code. Which `version` of Matlab are you using? And is it a 32-bit PC version?

Comment: I'm using Matlab on Mac, version 2013b

Comment: Maybe using XPath would be more generic https://www.thewizz.art/2022/01/03/how-to-get-all-the-node-values-from-an-xml-based-on-the-xpath-in-matlab/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
findExptID = ' wxyz ';
findYear = '';

xDoc = xmlread('myfile.xml');

allListitems = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('experiment');

for k = 0:allListitems.getLength-1
   thisListitem = allListitems.item(k);

   % Get the label element. In this file, each
   % listitem contains only one label.
   thisList = thisListitem.getElementsByTagName('exptid');
   thisElement = thisList.item(0);

   % Check whether this is the label you want.
   % The text is in the first child node.
   if strcmp(thisElement.getFirstChild.getData, findExptID)
       thisList = thisListitem.getElementsByTagName('years');
       thisElement = thisList.item(0);
       findYear = char(thisElement.getFirstChild.getData);
       break;
   end

end

disp(findYear);
```

Comment: I needed to change `thisElement.getFirstChild.getData` to `strtrim(char(thisElement.getFirstChild.getData))` to avoid whitespace problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that the issue is indeed occurring due to Java (inside `xmlread` so I'm not sure @sclarke81's solution will work). This is a classic error in dealing with Matlab's Java's underpinnings. Java has run out of memory (the heap space). You can try increasing it and seeing if that remedies the situation – this blog post from The MathWorks details how to check the heap size and how to adjust it from the preferences:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/04/26/controlling-the-java-heap-size/